# How to increase checkboxes size with css which work in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox

I have implemented many CSS methods to enlarge the size of checkboxes. Problem is that it does not work with Google Chrome. For example I tried http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/checkboxes/

Does someone know any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Styling checkboxes is risky business. It's one of those things that never seems to work consistently with all browsers.

Having said that, jQuery offers a plugin to do a replacement on checkboxes and radiobuttons

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ui-checkbox

Comment: Agreed, the only safe way to do this is to replace the HTML control with something else (image, css etc).  By far the easiest way to do that is to use jQuery and their UI controls.

Comment: But most of these plugin does not have enough size for checkboxes. Is there any plugin that control size of checkboxes. Thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

This new project seems promising as well https://github.com/mattSOLANO/ScrewDefaultButtonsV2